# Can there be a phase transition without change in entropy and volume?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, phase-diagram

**Context**: I'm studying basic thermodynamics.

My lecture notes pose a question, whether there can be a phase transition without a change in entropy or volume ? Do you have any hints on where to start from ?

---

**Idea 1**:
I know that $dG = 0$ during the equilibrium ($G$ is the Gibbs free energy).

If I take that route, I get: $dG = -SdT + VdP = 0$.

Something that I thought was that I'm interested in $dV,dS$ but my equation has $dT,dP$ in it, so perhaps a Legendre transformation would help here ?

I.e., $\widetilde{T} = G + TS - VP \Rightarrow d\widetilde{T} = dG + TdS + SdT -VdP - PdV = TdS -PdV$.

How would I proceed from now on ? If I plug $dS=0,dV=0$ in the equation I get $d\widetilde{T}=0$.

What if I claim that only $G$, from the various thermodynamic functions, is kept constant during the transition, therefore $\widetilde{T} \equiv G$, which contradicts  $\widetilde{T} = G + TS - VP$ ?

**Idea 2**: Another line of attack is to consider the Clapeyron equation which holds for the transition \begin{equation}\frac{dP}{dT} = \frac{\Delta S}{\Delta V}\end{equation}.

If both entropy and volume do not change, then I get an indefinite form: \begin{equation}\lim_{\Delta S\to 0,\Delta V\to 0} \frac{\Delta S}{\Delta V} = \frac{0}{0}\end{equation}

But how do I proceed from here on ?

Comment: In second order phase transitions the entropy and volume are continuous.

Comment: If there's zero change in entropy then the likelihood of transition in one direction is identical to the likelihood in the opposite direction.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: replace *entropy* by *free energy* and I'd agree ...

Comment: @JohnRennie  OK by me -- but comments can't be edited :-(

Comment: @Zet How do you know that $dG=0$?